# Python Selenium Get Text by Its Color

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i need to get a specific text from a website by the text color, in my case this color is rgb(209,196,233).

The text element in HTML:

```
<span style="color: rgb(209, 196, 233);">−14.64</span>
```

my code :

```
XYZ = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@style='color: rgb(209,196,233);']").text
```

When i execute, the code crashed with this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@style='color: rgb(209,196,233);']"}
```

What did i do wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your XPath is correct. But as the error says: Unable to locate element. You can use wait to "wait" until your element is located. For more, you can see: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

So you can do that as follows:

```
#import necessary parts
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#..your code for webdriver
#wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#After that get text from xpath
XYZ = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
"//span[@style='color: rgb(209, 196, 233);']"))).text
```

Comment: Thank you, it works... but for a while, there is another error appeared. My code tries to retrieve the text every 3 sec. After about 100 tries (more or less) the error appeared : 'Tselenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'

Comment: That is completely different error related to your other code parts. "Element is not attached to the page document" means that the web element is probably no longer in the HTML document. Probably; Element colour is refreshing and changing dynamically. If so best thing will be find better xpath. If not then Try, Catch Blocks may works in your situation.